# ESXi 5.5 + vCSA Upgrade

Tags: vmware-esxi, vmware-vsphere, vmware-vcenter

We are upgrading 4 hosts from ESXi 5 to 5.5
We are adding 4 more hosts with clean ESXi 5.5 installs
We are also upgrading our vCS 5 to the vCSA 5.5
Using Enterprise Plus Licensing

Issue:  I am trying to figure out the best way to make this transition.  Our 4 hosts are running about 100 VMs and the 4 hosts we are adding are clean slates.

This is what I am thinking... Please help me out guys

1. After the 4 new hosts are setup in the Data Center running clean ESXi 5.5 I will deploy the vCSA ovf and register the 4 hosts with the Linux based appliance.
2. Now I have 4 new ESXi 5.5 hosts registered and running with vCSA 5.5 but I still have my 4 old hosts with ESXi 5 and registered to the old WIndows vCS running about 100 VMs
3. At this point I am thinking of shutting down the VMs on my older 4 hosts and removing them from the Windows vCenter Server Inventory and simply registering them with the new vCSA
4. Will all my VMs be transferred over with the hosts if I shut them down and put the hosts into maintenance mode????
5. Now I should have all 8 hosts registered with my new vCSA.  But the original 4 hosts still need to be upgraded to ESXi 5.5
6. Move the 100 VMs to the new 4 hosts running ESXi 5.5 and upgrade the 4 older hosts.
7. Now I should have 8 hosts with ESXi 5.5 using the vCSA

   - Do I need the host running my Domain Controller to be the one vCSA is deployed to?  Or do i need to deploy the vCSA without a hostname using DHCP so I don't need to map it to DNS with a static IP.  Little confused on what to do about this upgrade regarding my DC.  Please help.

Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

Steps 1 and 2 are great, for step 3 simply add the existing hosts to the new VCSA, yes you'll have to drag all the VMs/Templates/Networks/Datastores to any new folder hierarchy as that'll be lost but the VMs will just migrate over just fine - no need for any VM or host power-offs.

Then all you need to do is vMotion the VMs from the old hosts to the new ones and then simply maint-mode/shutdown the old hosts, boot them off the 5.5 .iso file, run the updater and reboot - that should be it.

Oh and 'Do I need the host running my Domain Controller to be the one vCSA is deployed to" - no :)

Comment: So your saying to just unregiser the old hosts from the Windows vCS and keep their VMs running.  Then add them to the new vCSA through add host wizard?

Comment: My only concern is I need to have my DC setup before deploying the vCSA so I can set a static hostname/IP.

Comment: Should I unregister the host (running my DC) from Windows vCS.  Then just deploy the ovf vCSA from that host so I can set static hostname/IP.  From there I could add the 4 new hosts that are clean slates.

Comment: The other 3 hosts that are still registered with the Windows vCS would then just repeat the process of un-registering them from the Windows vCS, keep all the VMs running, then use the add host wizard on my new vCSA to import them?

Comment: You don't need to unregister anything, simply add the existing hosts to the new VCSA, that's all - seriously, nothing else - the DC will carry on working, you don't need to change anything, just add the hosts to the vC - certainly there's nothing you need to do to the AD setup.